# How to compare two indexes of an array (not values of these indexes)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, anagram

I need to make a program that defines whether the word is anagram or not. Well, here is my code. The lines marked with `## here` reflect the main problem. I need to define indexes of `word1` and `word2` of the first and second `for` loops and then compare them. If these indexes are similar then program misses the word (because it occurs twice while iterating). I know, the code has not been completed yet

```
text_sample = 'text goes here'

c = 0
i = 0
isanagramma = 0
n = len(text_sample)
while c < len(text_sample):
    for word1 in text_sample:
        for word2 in range(1,n):
            s1 = sorted(word1)
            s2 = sorted(text_sample[word2])
            index1 = text_sample.index(word1)                ## here
            index2 = text_sample.index(text_sample[word2])   ## here
            if index1 == index2:                             ## here
                continue                                     ## here
            if s1 == s2:
                isanagrama+=1
            i+=1
    c+=1
print(isanagramma)
```

Comment: unclear to me, you have a string of space separated 'words' and you want to compare all words to see if you have anagrams? give a desired output for your `text_sample` input

Comment: I see several problems in the lines before the marked lines. I suggest you should debug this to see what you have in each of the variables. Then, I suggest you should create a verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: text_sample contains some text where among the words I must find anagrams (I'm making type convertion to List)

Comment: if one string is anagram or not -  is checked with respect to another string. Can you explain what do you mean by - `I must find anagrams`? As @Chris_Rands said - it would be better if you give expected output for the given input

Comment: for example, `text_sample = 'The section number five of the contract contained the notices about the terms of delivery'` Words "section" and "notices" are anagrams , the output must be like this `section-notices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text_sample = 'text goes here ttex'

s = text_sample.split(" ")
isanagramma = 0
for i in range (0,len(s)-1):
    for x in range(i+1,len(s)):
        if sorted(s[i]) == sorted(s[x]):
            print ("is anagram :{} and {}".format(s[i],s[x]))
            isanagramma += isanagramma 
        else:
            print ("not anagram :{} and {}".format(s[i],s[x]))

print (isanagramma)
```

output:

```
not anagram :text and goes
not anagram :text and here
is anagram :text and ttex
not anagram :goes and here
not anagram :goes and ttex
not anagram :here and ttex
1
```